# Deserializing Rest Obects

Tags: rest, serialization, wsdl

With WSDL the information about the data is available to the client app through a link.

If I were to serialize an object with rest using the json format, how would the client know how to deserialize it?  How would they know the data structure?  Is it trial and error?

Example Object to serialize and deserialize

string Username
int Age
DateTime SignupDay

How does the client know the structure of the class?

Answer (score 0):

The client should specify what formats they will accept via the Accept header. Your service should either return one of the supplied formats or a `406 Not Acceptable`. If you need to, you should create your own custom MIME type.

Before the call, the client knows the structure from the documentation of the API or the documentation of the custom MIME type. After the call, the client knows the structure because it's holding an instance of the response.

Comment: JSON is assumed, I should have written that.